# I need help with a stripped version of Ubuntu

Tags: printing, software-center, ham-radio

I installed Andy Linux on my pc.  IT IS a mini or stripped version of Ubuntu with some ham radio programs installed.  It does not have software center or some of the programs for services, and other administration task.  How can I add software center and or the full version without removing the ham radio programs?

How can I setup a wireless printer?

Comment: Might be best to separate your two questions out rather than combine them in one question.

Comment: Download through [launch pad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/13.10-0ubuntu4.1) and do manual install , maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have apt-get or aptitude? You can probably do `sudo apt-get install software-center` if so.